# revert vs. update for uncommited changes

Tags: mercurial

Suppose you have commit some changes, and then somehow deleted/modified some files by accident.

Which would be better? Using `revert` oder `update`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two big differences between running **hg update -C** and doing **hg revert -a**

1. Update will move your parent up to the tip of the head of the branch
2. Update will no create any backup files

The revert command on the other hand

1. Creates backups of all reverted files (unless you give --no-backup command)
2. Does not change your working directories parent changeset.

Now which is better? Depends in which of the things listed above you want.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you want `revert` -- it alters your working directory without altering the output of the `hg parents` command.  Your `parent revision` is the "currently checked out revision" and will become the "parent" of your next commit.  You don't need to alter that pointer, so just `revert`.